# Heroku no reconoce las views de mis rutas dinámicas

Tags: javascript, nodejs, heroku, views

Logre hacer "Correctamente" un deploy de mi app en Heroku, utilizo rutas dinamicas para los nros internos de supuestos clientes, pero en cuanto voy a la ruta dinamica me sale el siguiente error en el navegador:

`Internal Server Error`

Cuando verifico los `logs` de mi servidor heroku recibo la siguiente respuesta:

`Error: Failed to lookup view "matriculado" in views directory "/app/views"`

La ruta de mi proyecto de trabajo es la siguiente:

```
app
 |
 |-->node_modules
 |-->source
       |
       |-->views
```

Ahora, eh investigado y además por lo que me devuelven los logs de Heroku es por que no reconoce la ruta de mis views correctamente, la primera vez que hice el deploy tenia este script en mi app.js:

`app.set('views', path.resolve(__dirname, 'views'));`

Con el mismo funciona la view de index, pero no las estáticas, vi que si coloco el siguiente comando debería funcionar:

`app.set('views', path.join(process.cwd() + '/source/views'));`

Sin embargo ocurre la misma situación, index.pug se encuentra dentro de views al igual que matriculado.pug, sin embargo cuando va a buscar el archivo index lo encuentra sin problemas, pero con matriculado no es lo mismo, sigue intentando buscar dentro de `app/views` en vez de `app/source/views`

**Mis Routes**

```
router.get('/:nroMatricula', async (req, res)=>{   const matriculadoBuscado = await matriculado.find({nroMatricula: req.params.nroMatricula})   res.render('matriculado', {datos: matriculadoBuscado});
```

Comment: De lo que has mostrado no parece que estes usando un path dinamico, normalmente este tipo de paths se visualizan con un `/sources/views/:dynamicPath`

Comment: Lo siento, olvide adjuntar mis Routes en la pregunta, son así:
`router.get('/:nroMatricula', async (req, res)=>{
  const matriculadoBuscado = await matriculado.find({nroMatricula: req.params.nroMatricula})
  res.render('matriculado', {datos: matriculadoBuscado});
});`
Donde el nro de matricula es lo que se obtiene de como dato dinamito para las routes.